# Sharepoint window scroll not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, scroll

I have this HTML generated by my SharePoint page (clipped):

```
<body scroll="yes" onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();" class="v4master" style="overflow: scroll" spellcheck="false">
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/Lists/List/EditNewForm.aspx?ID=2&amp;Source=https%3A%2F%2Fsp2010-test%2Eatwss%2Ecom%2FLists%2FList%2FAllItems%2Easpx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm" style="overflow: scroll">

// some html here

<div id="competenceTotalSum" style="position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color:gray" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){       
        $("form#aspnetForm").bind("scroll", function(e){
            alert("scroll");
            $("#competenceTotalSum").css("top", $(this).scrollTop() + 400);
        });
    });
</script>

// some html here

    </form>
</body>
```

Event `scroll` not firing. I changed `scroll` attribute of `body`, overflow properties of `body` and `form`, tried to bind `scroll` event to different objects (`window`, `body`, `form`). When change `scroll` event to `click` event - it fires. I didn't find any reasons of it except `overflow` property of scrolled element.

Comment: bind() has been deprecated in favor of "on" - see here: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: @Sebastian, thanks, but it didn't solved problem. With on() it doesn't works too.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion there - the comment above was only a suggestion for your code in general. See my answer below for the actual answer. ;)

Comment: @Sebastian, both answers didn't help me. For my purposes I used $(window).resize event and fixed position of block.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's kind of old Question but still this might be helpful for other, I wanted to implement scroll to top feature in one of my share point project.

After breaking my head around few hours. I got it working with below code.

actually `$(window).scroll()` wont fire in share point, I use there master id which is `('#s4-workspace')` to get it work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offset = 220;
    var duration = 1000;

  jQuery('#s4-workspace').scroll(function() {

        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            jQuery('.arrowToTop').fadeIn(duration);
        } else {
            jQuery('.arrowToTop').fadeOut(duration);
        }
    });

    jQuery('.arrowToTop a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
       jQuery('#s4-workspace').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
        return false;
    }) });
```

I have used below CSS style

```
.arrowToTop {
   display: none;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   right: 20px;    
   z-index: 9999;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 70px;
   height:70px;
} 

.arrowToTop a{     
    width: 70px;
    height:70px; 
    display: block;
     background: url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat left 0;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, finally a version that works.. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

As it looks to me right now, form#aspnetForm shouldn't even have a working scroll bar, right?

`overflow: scroll` only makes sense together with `height` or `max-height`. (Additionally, I'd replace `overflow: scroll` with `overflow: auto` so you only show the scroll bar you actually *need* to show, which most likely is the vertical scroll bar.

If you want to track scrolling on the whole document, change your code to

```
$("body").on("scroll", function(e){
    alert("scroll");
    $("#competenceTotalSum").css("top", $(this).scrollTop() + 400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check following code and see if it can help you. I have added height to form.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body scroll="yes" onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();"  style="overflow: scroll"  class="v4master" spellcheck="false">
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post"  style="height:100px;overflow: scroll"  action="/Lists/List/EditNewForm.aspx?ID=2&amp;Source=https%3A%2F%2Fsp2010-test%2Eatwss%2Ecom%2FLists%2FList%2FAllItems%2Easpx" 
    onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm"  >

// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br><br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>
// some html here<br>

<div id="competenceTotalSum" style="position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color:gray" >asdsa</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){       
        $("form#aspnetForm").bind("scroll", function(e){
            alert("scroll");
            $("#competenceTotalSum").css("top", $(this).scrollTop() + 400);
        });
    });
</script>

// some html here

    </form>
</body>
```